# Copy 100.000 Files using the Threadpool

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have to copy thousends of files the fastest possible way. 
Is it a good idea to use the `ThreadPool` for that?

Can i Enqueue so many items ?

Any better solution ?

#### Update

I want to copy to different network locations (random).

Comment: If you're going to write the files to a single physical drive, it's pointless; if you're going to have many physical recipients at once, it's a good idea. No way to tell from the details provided.

Comment: I copy to many other network locations.

Comment: @dknaack with the update: how are you doing the writing / copying? Again, this is *still* massively IO bound - even more so (a CPU ran run laps around a local disk, and a local disk can run laps around a network); are you copying the same data to all locations?

Comment: No, i have one source server, high performance RAID with many disks. And i need to copy all files to other servers. I pick one file and choose randomly another destination server. I want to keep the copy rate as constant as possible.

Comment: @dknaack - multiple-redundant backups?

Comment: I don't agree/ It depends a lot on the network speed of the network locations in relation to the disk speed. It could be beneficial to have multiple threads if they are to a number of different slow network locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the target destinations are connected over networks, multiple threads or an asynchronous thread pool will certainly speed up the overall transfer, especially if the 'thousands of files' are small enough so that the latency of setting up a connection takes a significant part of the transfer time.

You should make the number of transfer tasks/threads configurable so as to tune your system to the network resources available.  Doing that in an adaptive, automated fashion would be an interesting exercise:)

Using only one thread/async task would result in truly dire performance, especially with high-banddwidth, but high-latency, links where the connection setup-time for each file is very significant - the network would be grossly under-utilized.

Answer (score 10):

You are going to be IO bound, not CPU bound... not much point using many threads here. That could actually make things *slower* (especially on rotating disks - you will be adding seek time and reducing the buffer effectiveness). IMO, you might as well process them sequentially on a single background thread.

Comment: @MartinJames yes; not "today", but not very long ago either; disk scatter ahoy!

Answer (score 4):

If the files are being copied to the same destination disk/network location or from same source disk/network location, then the bottleneck will be the data read/write and not CPU, so using multiple threads will be of no use.

Comment: You should try it again - with a modern disk with 16 GB of cache and/or an SSD.  I'm not saying that I've tried it either and I would be interested in the results.  You may well be right in the case of disks on the same box, (which, as we now know, is not the OP case).

Comment: Ya, the OP may do well to try it.